# The bigger the sales and the higher the sales /are

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases

Let's say you are asked about how teamwork can affect the sales of a company. You say:

> I believe the stronger our team is, the bigger our rewards and the higher our sales will be. (My construction)

Or

> I believe the stronger our team is, the bigger our rewards and the higher our sales. (Corrected by omitting the last 2 words)

My newest construction:

> I believe the stronger our team is, the bigger our rewards and the higher our sales are.

My point here is, which is correct here. It a **set phrase** BUT I don't know how to construct it correctly to mean what I am trying to say.

P.S.: I believe that the corrected sentence2 is wrong...

Comment: side info: I would say "I belive **that**..."

Comment: Nice. Cheers hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your corrected sentence2 is correct...
The second variant is even more usual than the first one. The third one is also Ok. As to my experience the 2nd version is the best. You may find additional information here:

[The…the… with comparative adjectives](https://www.englishgrammar.org/thethe-comparative-adjectives/)

[What are sentences like “the longer X, the more Y” called and can they be used in formal written English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/what-are-sentences-like-the-longer-x-the-more-y-called-and-can-they-be-used-i)